# VIsual Studio Code not seeing Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda

So I've finished building my new PC, basically a fresh windows install with just some drivers and basic programs. After setting everything up I decided to install Anaconda and VSCode. Thats what I did and that is ALL I installed. I set up environment paths to the python.exe. Despite this when I try to import numpy in VSCode it doesnt work.

I tried running this tiny bit of code to see if VSCode could import conda modules:

```
import numpy as np
data = [1, 32, 345, 2, 543, 48237, 3, 432, 378, 946, 234, 12, 345, 1, 2, 3, 4567, 32]
print(np.mean(data)
```

Running the above code resulted in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Daniel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Daniel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Daniel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\dev\test\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried seeing if Visual Studio Code is using the correct interpreter just in case but just like I expected there is only one interpreter to choose from

EDIT: It does work in command line as expected and I tried doing conda install numpy with no success

EDIT2: Solved! I noticed the following error in my VS Code:

```
File *name* cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
```

So I went into powershell and allowed to run signed scripts by typing in  'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned' and everything worked like a charm afterwards

Comment: does it work in command line? Is the error just in VS Code?

Comment: ok, if VSCode and python are realy THE ONLY things you installed, than you forget to install numpy. 
[link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Pythons-NumPy-library-in-Visual-Studio-Code)

Comment: @VaibhavVishal yep works in python shell perfectly it looks like its VS Code thats causing issues

Comment: @MateuszBoruch numpy comes with conda preinstalled last I checked but in any case I tried to install numpy separately again and it results in the same error

Comment: anaconda makes a virtual-env by default. make sure VS Code is using that virtual-env. Use the official Python extension for VS Code by Microsoft to easily select venv in VS Code.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal it looks like it was already using that enviroment. When I go  into 'select interpreter' theres only one enviroment there which is the conda one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this one myself. I noticed the following error in my VS Code:

```
File *name* cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
```

So I went into powershell and allowed to run signed scripts by typing in  'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned' and everything worked like a charm afterwards

In any case thanks to everyone who tried to help, turns out i have to learn to read